# NodeJS socket.io show data from MySQL realtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on `NodeJS` and `socket.io`.

The current function is working good to display data from mysql database to table.
Now I need the page view auto update/refresh (realtime) if there is a new data received.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="display"> </div>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();
  socket.on('connect', function() {
    document.getElementById("socketio").innerHTML = "socket connected";
  });
  socket.on('showrows', function(rows) {
    var html='';
    for (var i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
      html += rows[i].product_name + ' ' + rows[i].product_price + '<br>';
    }  
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = html;
    console.log(rows);
  });
</script>
```

and `index.js`

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('testsql.html');
  //res.sendfile('/login/');
});
http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: "crud_db"
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('a client connected');

    con.query('SELECT * FROM product',function(err,rows){
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log('Data received from Db:\n');
      console.log(rows);
      socket.emit('showrows', rows);
    });
 });
```

My question, how to make a realtime function to web page if there is a new data received?

Comment: you'll need something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-events which will notify you about the changes, then your socket should publish the changes

Comment: Hi, could you give me an example with my current code?

Comment: maybe its somewhat similar topic with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945520/how-can-i-know-an-update-event-on-mysql-using-nodejs-with-mysql, but at the end I guess either a loop is needed to listen the db update, or if update is triggered from an input, also notify somewhere in your code to update user. just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

I never try it before, but I think you can do something like this

1.first listen an event when there is new submitted data

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('new data', function (data) {
       socket.emit('broadcast', data) // send it to the client
    })
})
```

2.store the io instance to app.locals:

```
app.locals.io = io
```

3.then, consider you have an endpoint to create a new data:

```
app.post('/product', function (req, res) {
    const sql = `INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES (${req.body.name}, 
    ${req.body.price})`
    
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        const io = req.app.locals.io
        io.emit('new data', { data: result })
    })
})
```